# Braintree PayPal Integration

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

Do Braintree API support PayPal integration for web/desktop application? Or it is just for mobile apps/websites? If Braintree API support PayPal integration for desktop application, then what steps should be follow if I am using PHP as programming language?
P.S. I have already googled it and found no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Braintree supports PayPal in web browsers served from a PHP backend.

First you'll need to install the PHP SDK: That class is not built in and must be downloaded and required before it is available. Have you downloaded the latest PHP SDK?

This is an example of the code you need to initialize the SDK but with dummy values:

```
<?php

require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('your_merchant_id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('your_public_key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('your_private_key');
```

Next, you'll need to setup the client. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/setup for download instructions.

[This tutorial](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/paypal) demonstrates exactly how to get started with the coding.

Once you have completed this integration against [Braintree's sandbox](https://www.braintreepayments.com/get-started), you will need to [sign up for a production account](https://braintreepayments.com/signup).

Comment: Hi mickeyreisis I have followed steps given in link but facing "class Braintree_ClientToken not found" error when I try to create Client token. I am including php library provided by Braintree and can successfully make transactions using credit card info on sandbox as well as live server. What I am missing??

Comment: I added some information about downloading the latest PHP code. Have you required Braintree.php in your code?

Comment: Thanks mickeyreisis .. I am done with integrating Paypal with Braintree.. I was using old version of library that's why i was getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [general PHP SDK for Braintree's API](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php).  It seems to be a pretty complete SDK with good samples and everything put together for you.

As a side note, I'm curious why you're planning on using Braintree instead of PayPal directly..??  I still prefer hitting PayPal's existing API because they're so mature and have so many features.  This [PHP library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) makes all of the calls very simple, too.

Braintree is unique in what they're doing with their SDK's, but as you've noticed, they really seem to be focused more on mobile.  They came into PayPal with lots of big companies already using it, which is why PayPal acquired them, but they don't offer anything PayPal doesn't already offer, and in my experience it's still cheaper to just use PayPal directly.

I may be missing out on something I haven't understood, though, so if you have any specific reasons you'd like to go with Braintree I'd love to know!

Comment: This is general documentation. I have already integrated braintree api and playing with it in different ways. I wanted to know about Paypal integration with Braintree. Yes i personally think that paypal is complete in every aspect but Braintree api integration was requirement of client i am working for.